# Creating Fixed Texts with Bootstrap3 & CSS3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So, i'm making a User Control Panel on Bootstrap 3, i know a few things about it and have worked multiple times on it, but the only problem i have is that i lack of knowledge on CSS(3) to achieve this or atleast on how to approach said objective:

My objective is to create some kind of Mobile Data Computer screen where on each corner of my page i put a fixed text

[image: Screen Example]

What would be the best approach to achieve it and on a Fixed position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is so simple, that I'm not sure I understand the question right.

HTML:

```
<div class="box box--tl">Top left</div>
<div class="box box--tr">Top right</div>
<div class="box box--bl">Bottom Left</div>
<div class="box box--br">Bottom right</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ddd;
    position: fixed;
}
.box--tl{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.box--tr{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.box--bl{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.box--br{
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zufe7cz0/

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answer, i ended up making a header and footer with the fluid container and also a few span with the pull-right and left classes. It was so simple that i couldnt even manage to do it lol

Edit: As i feel the guy who answered first was also right, i decide to move then answer to his reply.